# if a secure page does a postback, will the postback continue to be on secure page?

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I am using ASP.NET wizard, and it does postback to go to next step of the wizard or something.  I need this particular page to be secure (making the entire site secure is NOT an option).  Will the postback retain "https"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page where you have the wizard has an *https* url and the form **action** goes to the same page, the POST will be secure too.

Comment: this is not happening though.  the postback is taking it to http, instead of https.

Comment: Is there a `<base href="http://somehost/" />` within the <head> of the HTML page?

Comment: good point, I think there may be. But it works on this other page I have that has the exact same head element, so I do not know.